# PHP ForEach Error

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

Here is my code:

```
<?php
  $query1 = 'SELECT * From Drink';
  $GetName= mysql_query($query1);?>

<?php foreach ($GetName as $GetNames) : ?>
        <?php echo $GetNames['Name']; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

The error I'm getting is this:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in (removed for privacy) on line 16
```

I've looked at other questions similar to this one, and they don't quite answer the question. I'm not interested (currently) in finding a different way to go about doing this. I already have an alternate way, but I was taught this way and I'd like to know why it is failing.

It isn't a problem with the database or the query, because this:

```
<?php
  if ($GetName) {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($GetName)) {
                $name = $row["Name"];
                echo "$name<br>";
            }
        }
```

Works just fine.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `if (is_array($GetName)) {`

Comment: Is `$GetName` a mysql_ resource, or an array?

Comment: mysql_* is depricated, any way checkout the answer

Comment: You have a solution that works just fine, using `mysql_fetch_array` in  a `while` loop. Use that.

Comment: check if the var is an array first with is_array(), but it looks like in this case its a resource. FYI, use PDO or ADO library or odbc_connect() instead of mysql_... like IOIO MAD said its deprecated

Comment: Great, I took a class in PHP last spring, and the way they taught me how to loop through arrays is already depreciated?

Comment: Oh wait, you're talking about the method to connect to the database as being depreciated? I know, I had a PDO connection originally, but it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got it working. The problem was the way I connected to the database. Once I switch to PDO, as IOIO MAD implied, it worked just fine. Also Kudos to Itay Moav -Malimovka, because his suggestion did get rid of the error. Thanks for all of your help everyone, I'm glad I got this resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Reason is what returns from a MySQL query is a resource. And that does not implement the iterator interface, which allow foreach to work on.

U need to loop and in each time, to see the new result set, u need to call `mysql_fetch_array($GetName)` until it returns false. That's when u stop to loop.

There is ABSOLUTELY no other simple way

In other words, u need to use the `while`. If u use an extension like PDO, u can use stuff like `fetchALL`

Read the PDO and MySQLi manuals for more options.

Comment: Well that's progress at least. I added:

$test = mysql_fetch_array($GetName)

then changed it to:

<?php foreach ($test as $GetNames) : ?>

Now I'm not getting the error, but what is returning doesn't match what's in the database.

Comment: $test is only ONE record. U need to loop on the reordS and on each record. Use the `while` that is the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Ty this

```
foreach ($GetNames as $GetName => $row)
{

     //echo as you like
    echo ... $row['Name'] ;
}
```

Comment: As I said, I know there are other ways to do it. I would like to know why this way isn't working, when it has in the past.